# Reading a random word from a file

Tags: java, for-loop, random

I am learning about file reading and exception handling and I found this code online for a Hangman game program. Can someone please break down what the for loop does in the beginning of the program when reading the file? I'm so far only aware of the while loop method on reading the file and printing out whats on it. But I am not sure how this person used a for loop to read from a list of words in a file.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = "words.txt";
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        ArrayList words = new ArrayList();
        String word;

        for(; fileScan.hasNext(); words.add(word)) //I am not sure what this code is doing
            word = fileScan.next();...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: That line does the following: 1) it checks to see if there is a another word in the file `fileScan.hasNext()` 2) it save the next word in the file to the `String` variable `word` in `word = fileScan.next()` 3) then it appends that string to the `ArrayList` `words` using `words.add(word)`. It's a strange way to hack a `for` loop and would be clearer as a `while` loop.

Comment: Interesting! thank you, I would have thought that this would have been better as if statements but with while loops, wouldn't you have to have to initialize `word` to something? Assuming you meant `while(fileScan.hasNext()) {
    words.add(word);
    word = fileScan.next();
   }`

Comment: @AustinKootz I tested the while loop above and I had to initialize the String word.

Comment: @janny In a for loop, the `increment` which is `for( nope; nada; HERE)` is executed last, *after the code from the body of the loop has been run*. Which is why I said it was a strange hack.

Comment: @janny Thus, the while loop equivalent would be `while(fileScan.hasNext()){word = fileScan.next(); words.add(word);}`

Comment: @janny Should I post those comments as an answer?

Comment: @AustinKootz I missed that haha Thank you again! This makes more sense:))

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop has three elements to detail how it should behave:

```
for (<initial action>; <condition for continuing>; <action per iteration>) {
    doSomething();
}
```

To the best of my knowledge none of those 3 elements is compulsory. A for-loop like `for(;;) { <body> }` is quite valid and simply runs for ever or until the code in the body of the loop reaches a break condition.

In the code you listed:

- the `<initial action>` is empty
- the `<condition for continuing>` is that there are more words in the filescan
- the `<action per iteration>` is to add the current word to the ArrayList

Since Java 6 (?) there is also the possibility to write more flexible for-loops where iterable lists are concerened as in this pseudo code:

```
for (Item s : listOfItems) {
    doSomething(maybe with s);
}
```